# Django Foreign Key

Tags: python, django

[Models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6H4zB.png)

[Shell Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SztWE.png)

--**CODE**--

```
    newArtist = Artist(name= "GBA",year_formed=1990)  
    newArtist.save()  
    album1 = Album(name = 'a',artist = newArtist)  
    album2 = Album(name = 'b',artist = newArtist)  
    album3 = Album(name = 'c',artist = newArtist) 
    album1.save()
    album2.save()
    album3.save()
    allAlbums = Album.objects.all()
```

Hey, I am pretty new to Django so have been going through the documentation diligently but have an error I for the life of me can't figure out! The problem lies when dealing with the filter property.

There are 2 classes in my models file: Artist and Album. Artist is also a foreign key of Album as an Artist can have many albums. Currently I have 3 albums instances created, all saved under the Artist "newArtist" who's name is "GBA".

The problems I'm facing are
1)When attempting to filter using the artist name "GBA" an empty query set was returned

2)However when I switched the specifier to "newArtist.id" it populated the query set successfully.
Am confused as to why the artist name did not work, was it a syntactical/logic/Django rule error?

If anyone needs to see further code snippets/output, please let me know.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please show your code, as text, in the question.

Comment: Your code looks fine so I wonder if you've an exact match on the name field.

Comment: You could try `Album.objects.filter(artist__name__icontains=newArtist.name)` . It would search for the Albums where the artist name contains (case insensitive) `newArtist.name` . Part of Django's ORM.

Comment: @Nifled Didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
newArtist = Artist.objects.create(name= "GBA", year_formed=1990) 

album1 = Album.objects.create(name = 'a', artist = newArtist)  
album2 = Album.objects.create(name = 'b', artist = newArtist)  
album3 = Album.objects.create(name = 'c', artist = newArtist) 

allAlbums = Album.objects.all()
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your answer till now!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Ry10p/django-Plugis/blob/master/courses/models.py

Same answer for the other question brotha!

look in the line 52 of my script!

-Cheers

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your answer till now!